# how to create hook from python to send data to mixpanel using dev token

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-2.7, mixpanel

I want to create a hook from my python code to send user data to mixpanel from signals.py in login and logout. 
Seen examples using api key and secret keys but I have only the dev auth token.

Also i want to retrieve data from that hook later on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mp = Mixpanel(<PROJECT_TOKEN>)
mp.track(<unique id>, <Event name>, <event data json>)
```